# How to replace XML tag text in T-SQL taking into account XML namespaces

Tags: xml, t-sql, replace, namespaces

I have the following code in T-SQL:

```
declare @x1 xml = '<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer">2018-02-06T00:00:00.000+10:00</StartDateTime></ScheduleDefinition>'; 
select @x1 as [@x1]; 

declare @now datetime = {d'2018-02-07'}; 
set @x1.modify('replace value of (/ScheduleDefinition/StartDateTime/text())[1] with sql:variable("@now")'); 
select @x1 as [@x1];
```

It doesn't replace datetime values. And as far as I understand namespaces of both tags are the reason of this issue. 
If I delete namespaces everything works just fine.

Is it possible to replace tag text even if namespaces are mentioned in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
declare @x1 xml = '<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer">2018-02-06T00:00:00.000+10:00</StartDateTime></ScheduleDefinition>'; 
select @x1 as [@x1]; 

declare @now datetime = {d'2018-02-07'}; 
set @x1.modify('declare namespace NS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer";  replace value of (/ScheduleDefinition/NS:StartDateTime/text())[1] with sql:variable("@now")'); 
select @x1 as [@x1];
```

We just need to declare the namespace, and then to use it where we need.

Before:

```
<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer">2018-02-06T00:00:00.000+10:00</StartDateTime>
</ScheduleDefinition>
```

After:

```
<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer">2018-02-07T00:00:00.000</StartDateTime>
</ScheduleDefinition>
```

Also, you can check this documentation about other cases of handling namespaces - [Handling Namespaces in XQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/handling-namespaces-in-xquery)

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution and for the link! I have one more question: why there is no need to declare xmlns:xsd and xmlns:xsi?